# Unable to filter my list view in tablayout activity

Tags: listview, firebase, filter, searchview, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout activity containing 3 tabs. In one of the tab fragment I want to add search view to filter my list view. I have this list view in my 1st tab, there I want to filter list view by a field say user name. I tried it by adding an item to search view in the menu and setting its configuration in Tablayout activity.

To do so I had to set content to list view in this tablayout activity also then I filter it but I am not getting the filter list. For more info I am fetching this list view content from firebase.

So how can I filter this list view by search view in one fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found here an application example related to my problem:

https://github.com/ardhityawiedhairawan/FragmentSearchView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/androlite/androidfragmentsearchview/SearchFragment.java